# Define a common route pass-through or filter for all Python Flask Blueprint Routes

Tags: python, flask

In my Python Flask app I have Blueprint Routes defined that correspond to API endpoints,

```
# Submit Agreement (Insert or Update)
@bp.route('submitAgreement', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def submitAgreement():
   #...code...

# Get Existing Agreement
@bp.route('fetchAgreement', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def fetchAgreement():
   #...code...
```

I need to define a common route pass-through or filter that will perform authorization prior to executing the code. The authorization needs to be, if the URL contains the param `id=..`, check that that ID belongs to the logged-in user.

Is there a way to define a custom "aspect" or filter with this code in Python Flask?

Answer (score 0):

Flask offers an
`@app.before_request` decorator

You can substitute `app` for `bp` to apply the function you define to just the blueprint.